# How to slow down the swapping of an image used as the background of an html element?

Tags: html, reactjs, css-animations

I wanted to make a webpage more lively by adding a layered curve SVG from the webapp Haikei. My webpage has a toggle to switch between dark and light mode, but the SVG is set to a certain color beforehand. To combat this i made two SVG's one that has a white background and the other with a gray background for the different themes. When I toggle between the two modes there is also a transition: all 0.6 so that the colors of the webpage doesn't instantly snap for a better user experience. The issue now is that the changing of the background for the SVG part is instant. I had a CSS variable that is url("waveWhiteBG") under the light theme and url("waveGrayBG") for the dark theme. Here are the relevant code snippets:

CSS

```
:root {
  --background-primary: white;
  --background-secondary: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  --text-primary: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --text-secondary: white;
  --accent: rgb(47, 177, 177);
  --vertical-margin: 240px;
  --default-font-size: 40px;
  --bottomLink: url("src/assets/waveWhiteBG.svg");
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --background-primary: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  --background-secondary: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  --text-primary: rgb(213, 213, 213);
  --text-secondary: white;
  --accent: rgb(47, 177, 177);
  --bottomLink: url("src/assets/waveGrayBG.svg");
}


.ResourcesPage .bottomEdge {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1858/150;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 3000;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.ResourcesPage .layer {
  background: var(--bottomLink);
  z-index: 3000;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

and this is how I implemented changing the theme of the webpage:

```
const defaultDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage(
    "theme",
    defaultDark ? "dark" : "light"
  );

  const switchTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    setTheme(newTheme);
  };
```

from here I just made my main div element have data-theme={theme}. The main thing that I want is for the changing of the SVG being used as the background for the webpage to have a transition from one image to another.

I tried using transition: all 0.6s and also transition: background 0.6s, which threw an error, and transition: background-color 0.6s which all didn't work. There was a post before that uses transition: background-image but that is not compliant with standards. Can this be done with CSS and if not how will I go about it with JS/TS?